# Null pointer exception while trying to retrieve data using Mybatis

Tags: java, mybatis

I have tried to read data from Oracle database using mybatis.

I have written below query in db.xml :

```
<select id="selectItemPartNumberWithEco" resultType="String">
        SELECT ITEM_PART_NUMBER from CIS_ITEM_AGILE_ECO_DATA_TBL WHERE ECO_NUMBER IS NOT NULL
    </select>
    <select id="selectItemPartNumberWithoutEco" resultType="String">
        SELECT ITEM_PART_NUMBER from CIS_ITEM_AGILE_ECO_DATA_TBL WHERE ECO_NUMBER IS NULL
    </select>
```

my db.java(interface) file has following declaration :

```
public List<String> selectItemPartNumberWithEco() throws DAOException;
public List<String> selectItemPartNumberWithoutEco() throws DAOException;
```

My implementation class has following code :

```
public List<String> selectItemPartNumberWithEco() throws DAOException {
    return repoItemDAO.selectItemPartNumberWithEco();
}

public List<String> selectItemPartNumberWithoutEco() throws DAOException {
    return repoItemDAO.selectItemPartNumberWithoutEco();
}
```

I have called the above class as follows :

```
RepoServiceImpl repoServiceObj = new RepoServiceImpl();
List<String> existingDbAgileItemList = repoServiceObj.selectItemPartNumberWithEco();
List<String> newDbAgileItemList = repoServiceObj.selectItemPartNumberWithoutEco();
```

While executing my code i am getting null pointer exception.

How to select a column from DB using mybatis?

Comment: Could you please add the stack trace - and point out which line is the source of the NPE?

Comment: The nullpointerexception will usually point a line which indicates that something on that line is null. Which line do the exception point to?

Comment: Show your error console.